# Replace in one file with value from another file not working properly

Tags: bash, shell, awk, sed, scripting

I have two files. A mapping file and an input file.

> **cat map.txt**
>
> test:replace
>
> **cat input.txt**
>
> The word test should be replaced.But the word testbook should not be
>   replaced just because it has "_test" in it.

Using the below command to find in the file and replace it with value in mapping file.

```
awk 'FNR==NR{ array[$1]=$2; next } { for (i in array) gsub(i, array[i]) }1' FS=":" map.txt FS=" " input.txt
```

what it does is, searches for the text which are mentioned in map.txt and replace with the word followed after " : " in the same input file.
In the above example "test" with "replace".

**Current result:**

The word replace should be replaced.But the word replacebook should not be replaced just because it has _replace in it.

**Expected Result:**

The word replace should be replaced.But the word testbook should not be replaced just because it has "_test" in it.

so what i need is only if that word alone is found it has to be replaced. If that word has any other character clubbed then it should be ignored.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The contents of file `input.txt` are missing

Comment: @Inian Contents are given under "cat input.txt". I have given a sample statement for an example.

Comment: @lfc_07, there's no `replacebook` or `_test` or `_replace` in your input. Update your question, it's vague

Comment: Sorry. What's vague? Its all in the input.Please check. I'm replacing test with replace.

Comment: What the mapping file does is replaces the word with another word mentioned after ":"

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest Added more explanations.

Comment: @lfc_07, you don't get it. You've been asked from the very 1st comment **The contents of file input.txt are missing**. You have not posted the input and expected result.

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest Apparently the contents of the `input.txt` is _The word test should be replaced.But the word testbook should not be replaced just because it has "_test" in it._

Comment: @JamesBrown Thanks. It's working fine. but there's another complication here. Say the replacement word is the end of an statement and it ends like "test." or even "test," in middle of a sentence.
In that case it's not getting replaced cos it's followed by .(dot) or a ,(comma).

Any solutions in that case ?. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With GNU awk for word boundaries:

```
awk -F':' '
NR==FNR { map[$1] = $2; next }
{
    for (old in map) {
        new = map[old]
        gsub("\\<"old"\\>",new)
    }
    print
}
' map input
```

The above will fail if old contains regexp metacharacters or escape characters or if new contains `&` but as long as both use word consituent characters it'll be fine.

Comment: Any way to make the changes infile?
Earlier what i was using was a one liner,so will assign it to variable and overwrite the file.Not working here, that way.

Comment: Please ignore, i figured out.
Thanks Ed.

Answer (score 1):

`for` loop all the words and replace where needed:

```
$ awk '
NR==FNR {                     # hash the map file
    a[$1]=$2
    next
}
{
    for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)        # loop every word and if it s hashed, replace it
        if($i in a)           # ... and if it s hashed...
            $i=a[$i]          # replace it
}1
' FS=":" map FS=" " input
The word replace should be replaced.But the word testbook should not be replaced just because it has "_test" in it.
```

**Edit**: Using `match` to extract words from strings to preserve punctuations:

```
$ cat input2
Replace would Yoda test.
$ awk '
NR==FNR {                     # hash the map file
    a[$1]=$2
    next
}
{
    for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) {
        # here should be if to weed out obvious non-word-punctuation pairs
        # if($i ~ /^[a-zA-Z+][,\.!?]/)
        match($i,/^[a-zA-Z]+/)       # match from beginning of word. ¿correct?
        w=substr($i,RSTART,RLENGTH)  # extract word
        if(w in a)                   # match in a
            sub(w,a[w],$i)
    }
}1' FS=":" map FS=" " input
Replace would Yoda replace.
```

Comment: Thanks. It's working fine. but there's another complication here. Say the replacement word is the end of an statement and it ends like "test." or even "test," in middle of a sentence.
In that case it's not getting replaced cos it's followed by .(dot) or a ,(comma).

Any solutions in that case ?. Thanks.

Comment: @EdMorton One shouldn't answer these 2 minutes before falling asleep...

Comment: @lfc_07 Care to be more specific?

Comment: Deleted few words which are not even in replacement list.

Comment: So I understood. Could you please provide a sample?